# Golang regexp Boundary with Latin Character

Tags: regex, go, latin

I have a small tricky issue about golang regex.
seems `\b` boundering option doesn't work 
when I put latein chars like this.

I expected that `é` should be treated as a regular char..
but it's treated as one of boundering wards.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {   
    r, _ := regexp.Compile(`\b(vis)\b`)
    fmt.Println(r.MatchString("re vis e"))
    fmt.Println(r.MatchString("revise"))
    fmt.Println(r.MatchString("révisé"))
}
```

result was:

```
true 
false 
true
```

Please give me any suggestion how to deal with `r.MatchString("révisé")` as `false` ?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, `\b` word boundaries only support ASCII--the docs say `at ASCII word boundary (\w on one side and \W, \A, or \z on the other)`. The only option is probably to explicitly match for characters you consider a word boundary in the regex (spaces, newlines, full stops, end of string, etc)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that `\b` is only for boundaries around ASCII characters, as stated in the docs:

> at ASCII word boundary (\w on one side and \W, \A, or \z on the other)

And `é` is not ASCII. But, you can make your own `\b` replacement by combining other regex shortcuts. Here is a simple solution that solves the case given in the question, though you may want to add more thorough matching:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {   
    r, _ := regexp.Compile(`(?:\A|\s)(vis)(?:\s|\z)`)
    fmt.Println(r.MatchString("vis")) // added this case
    fmt.Println(r.MatchString("re vis e"))
    fmt.Println(r.MatchString("revise"))
    fmt.Println(r.MatchString("révisé"))
}
```

[Running this](https://play.golang.org/p/qzraxkOfYW) gives:

```
true
true
false
false
```

What this solution does is essentially replace `\b` with `(?:\A|\z|\s)`, which means "a non-capturing group with one of the following: start of string, end of string or whitespace". You may want to add other possibilities here, like punctuation.

Comment: This works great. Including punctuation at the end looks like: `(?:[[:punct:]]|\s|\z)`